# Is OOP usage justified here in this javascript scenerio?

Tags: javascript, oop

Is OOP justified here?

Today was my first day at work at a small start-up. The start-up has a whiz JS developer who has A LOT of custom js using OOP for features such as modal window. More importantly, he has made almost all data display(such as rows of data to be displayed with edit/delete buttons) into some form of javascript OOP representation.

One of the things we are trying to do is remove a bunch of use of modal and just display the contents outrightly on the main window. Usually this would just mean copy/pasting a bunch of html/php code that was otherwise shown in the modal window. However, since this dev has developed everything in OOP and all these UI-related objects are closely tied to each other, moving away from modal window appears to require a lot more labor/fixing.

When I took this job I was excited and thought I'd get some experience getting knee deep with practical OOP. But a day later, I am yet to see its utility and at worst seems very counterproductive.

Am I missing something? When is it a good/bad idea to use OOP in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good practical approach, but as with OOP in any other language, it can be either implemented well or poorly.  OOP techniques for JavaScript can properly separate code instead of having strictly utility methods, so I don't believe it's a bad idea.  But from the sounds of it, you may want to try to refactor the design to make it more simplified, and then move code around...

There are concerns with doing everything in JavaScript, depending on what's being done in it, such as security, maintainability, cross-browser support, and more.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

OOP can be a very powerful tool to ensure that rewriting code is not necessary and that code is maintainable, but if it is improperly done, it can have the opposite effect. [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern) are employed to make sure that code is maintainable, and OOP is a big part of that. [This book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) seems to be an authority on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Since pretty much everything in JavaScript is an object, it's difficult to avoid some degree of OOP-iness in your code. OTOH, most JavaScript frameworks focus more on the functional aspects of the language.

In any event, I suspect the problem you are really getting at is that there is insufficient decoupling between the UI and the data model. If so, then look at frameworks — such as knockout.js — that explicitly separate them.

I will say that OOP has a tendency to bend the brain into the wrong shape. I remember that in the early days of OOP and OOAD, the idea that objects should be responsible for rendering themselves to a GUI was extremely common. As problematic as this is, it was a direct consequence of the core OOP principle that the behaviour of an object should be coupled with its data.

Comment: Perhaps. I don't know much about OOP. But I find it crazy that display of certain data would be tied to a specific type of window. I'm too used to simply using a modal plugin and calling another php page that is served as a modal. To remove the modal, I could just copy paste the previous-modal'd php into the parent php page.

Comment: @Henry: It definitely sounds like you have a problem with tight coupling, which is solved by separating the data from the UI and linking them via an MVC or MVVM framework. This has nothing to do with OOP, *per se*. You can design your decoupled data model with or without OO (though I favour a relational rather than an OO view of data).

Comment: Appreciate you helping me untangle this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more specifics of his implementation, its hard to say whether or not is approach is good.  However, there is a strong trend in web applications to do heavy OO design (along with MVC or MVP design patterns) on the client in Javascript.  Additionally, much of the rendering of the page is done with Javascript as well- frameworks such as Backbone.js (or Knockout.js as mentioned above) for this purpose are very popular, and quite interesting.

Javascript itself is actually an extremely good Object oriented language (see what Douglas Crockford has to say about it), and is currently undergoing a sort of renaissance, especially with younger developers.